# iCloud NSFileManager API - game score storage

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager, icloud, uidocument, nsfilecoordinator

I currently have an iOS application for which I would like to enable iCloud score storage so that users will have their game progress synced across their devices. The users progress is stored in multiple plist files in the sandboxes documents folder.
I read a few articles online about iCloud and the various "helper classes" (NSFileManager, UIDocument, NSFileCoordinator etc.) but am a little confused which one is the right one for me (does NSFileManager do the job or will i need to subclass UIDocument).

The API's are all a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use iCloud with [Key-Value Data Storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW9). It's by far the simplest and most reliable at the moment, and suits your case perfectly.

Comment: will it be able to handle NSDictionary storage? As far as I know conflict resolution is also not available with kvs and iCloud. Is that correct?

Comment: Anything that will go into a plist will go into Key Value storage. There's automatic conflict resolution, the newest item wins. More info and a comparison here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html